# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Set<Future<File>>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<File>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I would compress a list of image file before uploading, but i have some doubts to convert type after using `map` a list of file, it return type List<Set<Future>>, not type List as I expect. How can I convert/cast to List of File in this situation, the compressImage function worked well with only one file. Thank you so much.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Im;  
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';  
List<File> compressImageList(List<File> tempfileList) async {
    
    List<Future<File>> compressedFileList =
        tempfileList.map((file) => {compressImage(file)}).toList();

    return compressedFileList ;
  }

  Future<File> compressImage(File tempFile) async {
  String postId = Uuid().v4();
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;
    Im.Image? imageFile = Im.decodeImage(tempFile.readAsBytesSync());
    final compressedImageFile =  File('$path/img_$postId.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(imageFile!, quality: 85));

    tempFile = compressedImageFile;
    return tempFile;
  }
```

i edit my function as below and it works , thank you.

```
 Future<List<File>> compressImageList(List<File> tempfileList) async {
List<File> compressedFileList = [];
await Future.wait(tempfileList.map((file) async {
  var compressImage2 = await compressImage(file);

  compressedFileList.add(compressImage2);
}).toList());
return compressedFileList;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, haven't tested it, but try removing the {} on the 6th line (as shown above). These brackets signify that it is a type set, which is being returned by `=>`. If using `=>` for a single statement you don't need to use brackets.

Comment: Yes, these brackets make dart add Set to returned values. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this;

```
List<File> compressImageList(List<File> tempfileList) {
  List<File> compressedFiles = [];
  tempfileList.forEach((file) async {
    final compressedFile = await compressImage(file);
    compressedFiles = [...compressedFiles, compressedFile];
  });

  return compressedFiles;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but seem you need to add Future.wait()